# Blender Source File Path

Tags: blend-files, path

How can I define path of source files such as video, image, etc relative to blend file instead of absolute path in Windows?

In blender, when I want to define path of source files I use their absolute path.

When I change blender file location, connection between blender file and the videos, images, ... linked to it get broken.

As I asked how can I define path of sources used in blender file, relative to blender file, instead of using absolute path in Windows?

Comment: I see if my source file name is my_file.mp4 e.g. if I change the path to //my_file.mp4 (if my_file.mp4 is in same location as blender file) , it works.
Wonder if there is a way to make all paths relative by default.

Comment: Use **Relative Paths** read the documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/2.79/data_system/files/relative_paths.html read also : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/file_paths.html

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/save_load.html#files-blend-relative-paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to illustrate cegaton's comment.

Filepaths in Blender **are saved as relative** by default.

You can still change them to absolute/relative though.
*File > External Data > Make all paths relative/absolute*.

[image]

You can also change this default behavior in preferences:
*Edit > Preferences > Save & Load*

[image]

On top of that, you can set default relative/absolute paths for some types of data (scripts, textures, etc...)
Just go to *Edit > Preferences > File Paths*

[image]